# Can't add data to firebase firestore Error: React Native: Possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 0) TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

[image]

React Native: Possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 0) TypeError: Network request failed

[image]

Comment: Check the network request in your browser's dev console and post it if you would.  Are you logged in to firebase?  Is it happening in server-side rendering, on your web page, or in server side code?  How are you authenticating?

Comment: I'm logged in firebase and can login/register account with firebase, but when I'm add data to firestore, I seen that problem